# No javascript errors in Chrome debugger but does not insert text

Tags: javascript

This code fails to insert text into the textarea - see html below.  I can't change the html - because this snippet is mimicing a real web page.  I just need to insert text into a textarea.

It doesn't work in Chrome or IE9.

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function insert_text() {
   //enumerate div sections and find where id = WIN_0_4
   var div = window.document.getElementById("WIN_0_4");
   if(div !== null)
   {
      var txtbox = div.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
      if(txtbox !== null)
         txtbox.value = document.frm.texttoinsert.value;
   }
}

</script>

<form name="frm">
<input type="button" id="clicker" value="Click me" />
<input type="button" value="insert" id="inserter" onclick="insert_text();" />

<input type="text" name="texttoinsert" />
</form>


<div id="WIN_0_536870917" arid=536870917 artype="View" ardbn="View Field2"      class="arfid536870917 ardbnViewField2" style="color:#0000FF">
some text here
</div>

<div id="WIN_0_4" arid=4 artype="Char" ardbn="Assigned To">
<label id="label4" class="label f6">Assigned To</label>
<textarea class="text sr " wrap="off" id="arid_WIN_0_4" cols="20" maxlen=254 arautocak=0 arautoctt=400 rows=1></textarea>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you want `<input type=text>` instead of `type=input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
var txtbox = div.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
```

with

```
var txtbox = div.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
```

Or better :

```
var txtbox = document.getElementById('arid_WIN_0_4');
```

As the name implies, `getElementsByTagName` returns more than one element.

Comment: I am puzzled by var txtbox = document.getElementById('arid_WIN_0_4');  But what if eg there was a textarea and a text input and possibly other types - would I then have to check each textbox object for type textarea???

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean. Do you want to change multiple inputs or just one ? If you want to change just the one with a give id, the cleanest and most efficient solution is to use this id to fetch the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
txtbox[0].value = document.frm.texttoinsert.value;
```